# Copying files to the SD Card. (From one location to another)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard

I have an application and associated data with it, I am able to copy this data from my **Assest** folder onto the **SD Card**, that is flawless. But I want to improve on this code and allow the user to specify the location on SD Card, as in where she wants to store the data. Here is my code, please suggest modifications. (I want to generate a similar popup, when a file is being downloaded from the internet and a pop-up asks the user to specify the download location, where I am confused is whether I have to custom make this pop-up or it is inbuilt) Following is my code:

```
  private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
    for(String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open(filename);
          out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/edu/" + filename);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
public void MakeFolder(){
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/edu");

if(!direct.exists())
 {
     if(direct.mkdir()){ //directory is created;
         copyAssets();
 }
}
```

Comment: can u please help me i am using same code what u mention but failed to copy image from assets tosdcard onButtonClick event can u please help me ?

Comment: Please refer to the accepted answer below, I have followed that and it works fine. Also nothing can be said unless access to your code is available. Please post your query as a new question.

Comment: can i discuss my code in chat room  with u i dnt have reputations to ask question

Comment: Sure, although you don't need reputation to ask a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android dialog to choose a directory or file based on AlertDialog will help you in this case.

http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2012/07/android-dialog-to-choose-a-directory-or-file-based-on-alertdialog/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code I prepared (With valuable inputs form Google):

```
public class Fexplorer extends ListActivity {


String B=null ;
private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
private String root;
private TextView myPath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.explorer_main);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
    Button OK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button Cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    OK.setOnClickListener(onOK);
    Cancel.setOnClickListener(onCancel);

    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    getDir(root);
}

private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Choose Location");
    B = dirPath; 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),B, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());    
    }

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];

        if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }else{
                item.add(file.getName());
            }
        }   
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);   
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File file = new File(path.get(position));

    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        if(file.canRead()){
            getDir(path.get(position));
        }else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();  
        }   
    }

    /*else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

      } */
}

 private View.OnClickListener onOK=new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){


        copy();
        Intent About = new Intent(Fexplorer.this,EduBridge.class);
        startActivity(About);

        }
    };

 private View.OnClickListener onCancel=new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){


            Intent About = new Intent(Fexplorer.this,EduBridge.class);
            startActivity(About);


        }
    };

    public void copy(){
                try {
                        File sourceFile = new File("/sdcard/edu/Brochure.pdf");
                        File destinationFile = new File(B+"/" + sourceFile.getName());
                        String X = (B+"/" + sourceFile.getName());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),X, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Fexplorer copyFileExample = new Fexplorer();
                        copyFileExample .copyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destinationFile) {
                try {
                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                                        destinationFile);

                        int bufferSize;
                        byte[] bufffer = new byte[512];
                        while ((bufferSize = fileInputStream.read(bufffer)) > 0) {
                                fileOutputStream.write(bufffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        }

                        fileInputStream.close();
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    }
```

In the Styles:

```
    <style name="MyFloatingWindow" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

The explorer_main XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity ="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/path"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/path"
    android:layout_height="308dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="No Data"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/empty"

    android:text="@string/DirB" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:text="@string/DirA" />
```

Finally The row.xml file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/rowtext"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="50sp"
     android:textSize="15dp" />
```